# Is it possible to use a portion of a website's screen as a gadget?

Tags: igoogle, gadget

My company's directory search is in the upper right hand portion of our home page. I'd like to be able to create a gadget that would simply show that section of the company site *without writing code to build a gadget*.  (Don't abuse me, this is WebApps, not SO; it's okay to be programming useless here.)

It would let me search the site from my iGoogle page, rather than loading the home page first.

I thought there would be a gadget that did this, by letting you designate a URL in the settings, and then either somehow letting you "snag" a region, or perhaps enter the pixel locations to define the box, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

There is not going to be an easy way to do this without it being a programming activity to accomplish it.  The "most clean" way that I have found to do this is to actually create a gadget that resembles the form and does the post to the proper location.